# How to set up a Tor-Server (Hidden Service) as a proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, tor

The goal is, being able to access the proxy anonymously, such that the host (proxy) doesn't know, where the request came from (of course with credentials).

The client should be able to acess `www.example.com` over the hosts ip, without the host knowing the clients ip.

Here's a example request route to `www.example.com`:
[image: ![Network-route]

- How would I **hookup a browser** to it?
- How would I connect using Python? (something proxy-chain like?)

Note: OS doesn't depend, programming language preferably Python

EDIT:

- The Client in my case should be able to specify:

  - Headers
  - request-method
  - site-url
- For the request which the hidden-service makes (so basically a proxy)

Comment: I think this question belongs to superuser

Comment: here is a reference that might be useful: https://jordan-wright.com/blog/2014/10/06/creating-tor-hidden-services-with-python/

Comment: Here is another useful reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVMjk9pj2Cw

Comment: Well yeah thanks, but setting the onion server itsself up isn't my issue. The issue is hooking a proxy to the onion address. And afterwards connecting to the proxy over the tor network. clearnet->tor->proxy->clearnet

Comment: So you want to protect your onion address with a secondary proxy?

Comment: Cinda. I want an onion addess, which acually is a proxy. 
The point is, acessing the proxy anonymously. Only protection of getting identified by the proxy-host.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because it wasn't clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Please update your question with exact details on what your requirements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to create a hidden service on tor from host to be able to communicate over tor network

basic flask proxy example (for more advanced proxy you can follow [this](https://gist.github.com/stewartadam/f59f47614da1a9ab62d9881ae4fbe656) code) i didnt test this code but you can fix errors:

```
"""
A simple proxy server, based on original by gear11:
https://gist.github.com/gear11/8006132
Modified from original to support both GET and POST, status code passthrough, header and form data passthrough.
Usage: http://hostname:port/p/(URL to be proxied, minus protocol)
For example: http://localhost:5000/p/www.google.com
"""
from stem.control import Controller
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, abort, Response, redirect
import requests
import logging

app = Flask("example")
port = 5000
host = "127.0.0.1"
hidden_svc_dir = "c:/temp/"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
LOG = logging.getLogger("app.py")


@app.route('/<path:url>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def root(url):
    # If referred from a proxy request, then redirect to a URL with the proxy prefix.
    # This allows server-relative and protocol-relative URLs to work.
    referer = request.headers.get('referer')
    if not referer:
        return Response("Relative URL sent without a a proxying request referal. Please specify a valid proxy host (/p/url)", 400)
    proxy_ref = proxied_request_info(referer)
    host = proxy_ref[0]
    redirect_url = "/p/%s/%s%s" % (host, url, ("?" + request.query_string.decode('utf-8') if request.query_string else ""))
    LOG.debug("Redirecting relative path to one under proxy: %s", redirect_url)
    return redirect(redirect_url)


@app.route('/p/<path:url>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def proxy(url):
    """Fetches the specified URL and streams it out to the client.
    If the request was referred by the proxy itself (e.g. this is an image fetch
    for a previously proxied HTML page), then the original Referer is passed."""
    # Check if url to proxy has host only, and redirect with trailing slash
    # (path component) to avoid breakage for downstream apps attempting base
    # path detection
    url_parts = urlparse('%s://%s' % (request.scheme, url))
    if url_parts.path == "":
        parts = urlparse(request.url)
        LOG.warning("Proxy request without a path was sent, redirecting assuming '/': %s -> %s/" % (url, url))
        return redirect(urlunparse(parts._replace(path=parts.path+'/')))

    LOG.debug("%s %s with headers: %s", request.method, url, request.headers)
    r = make_request(url, request.method, dict(request.headers), request.form)
    LOG.debug("Got %s response from %s",r.status_code, url)
    headers = dict(r.raw.headers)
    def generate():
        for chunk in r.raw.stream(decode_content=False):
            yield chunk
    out = Response(generate(), headers=headers)
    out.status_code = r.status_code
    return out
    
def make_request(url, method, headers={}, data=None):
    url = 'http://%s' % url

    # Pass original Referer for subsequent resource requests
    referer = request.headers.get('referer')
    if referer:
        proxy_ref = proxied_request_info(referer)
        headers.update({ "referer" : "http://%s/%s" % (proxy_ref[0], proxy_ref[1])})

    # Fetch the URL, and stream it back
    LOG.debug("Sending %s %s with headers: %s and data %s", method, url, headers, data)
    return requests.request(method, url, params=request.args, stream=True, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False, data=data)

def proxied_request_info(proxy_url):
    """Returns information about the target (proxied) URL given a URL sent to
    the proxy itself. For example, if given:
        http://localhost:5000/p/google.com/search?q=foo
    then the result is:
        ("google.com", "search?q=foo")"""
    parts = urlparse(proxy_url)
    if not parts.path:
        return None
    elif not parts.path.startswith('/p/'):
        return None
    matches = re.match('^/p/([^/]+)/?(.*)', parts.path)
    proxied_host = matches.group(1)
    proxied_path = matches.group(2) or '/'
    proxied_tail = urlunparse(parts._replace(scheme="", netloc="", path=proxied_path))
    LOG.debug("Referred by proxy host, uri: %s, %s", proxied_host, proxied_tail)
    return [proxied_host, proxied_tail]

controller = Controller.from_port(address="127.0.0.1", port=9151)
try:
    controller.authenticate(password="")
    controller.set_options([
        ("HiddenServiceDir", hidden_svc_dir),
        ("HiddenServicePort", "80 %s:%s" % (host, str(port)))
        ])
    svc_name = open(hidden_svc_dir + "/hostname", "r").read().strip()
    print "onion link: %s" % svc_name
except Exception as e:
    print e

app.run()
```

after runing this you will get a onion link like: "somelongstringwithnumber123.onion" with that onion link you can connect to host from client over tor network

Than you need to make request over tor network from host:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {}
session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'

r = session.get("http://somelongstringwithnumber123.onion/p/alpwebtasarim.com")
print(r.text)
```

im not gonna test that codes but i hope you understand the main idea.

Comment: Exactly, that would be a solution for one SITE_NAME. But now, there's the point: I want the Hidden service to use: The same Headers, request-method and the client being able to change the SITE_NAME. Soo basically the Hidden Service should be a proxy.

Comment: than you need to configure flask proxy like this example:
https://gist.github.com/stewartadam/f59f47614da1a9ab62d9881ae4fbe656

Comment: And how would I connect to it then?

Comment: ok wait i will edit my answer

Comment: Any updates about?

Comment: updated. you can simply do it this way but i wrote it for you to understand the logic i don't know if the code is working

Comment: You still didn't answer how to connect to it tho.

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii i didnt understand what are you asking bro first code for creating server(host) and second code for connecting server(client). text me on linkedin

Answer (score -1):

To use a Tor hidden service as a proxy, you must install Tor on the server. https://www.torproject.org/download/ has the programme.

After installing Tor, add these lines to your torrc file:

```
import socks
import socket

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Use the socket module normally, and all connections will go via the proxy.
```

To utilise the tor hidden service with a browser, set the browser to use the Tor SOCKS proxy on localhost:9050 and use the hidden service hostname for the target address, which can be found in the file titled "hostname" in HiddenServiceDir.

The python-stem library can automate starting and stopping the tor service, establishing and deleting hidden services, and getting the hidden service's onion address.

Comment: I don't need a proxy, which givesl me acess to the Hidden Web. I Need the reverse part of that.