# How can I set up a proxy server as a Tor hidden service?

Tags: proxy, tor, proxy-server

How can I create a proxy server on a remote machine as a Tor service? I want to access the proxy server using the Tor network such that the traffic of my local machine is routed over Tor network to the hidden service on remote server and then to the clearnet....effectively showing the ip of the remote server as source ip.
The goal is to access this proxy service using the onion address and Tor network.
How would this be implemented and How would I connect to this server if its IP is not known and only its onion address is known.
Setting up a Tor service is already achieved, what I am asking is, how can I create a proxy server that is accessible using the onion address of the Tor server.
Someone has already asked a similar question but I didn't see a satisfactory answer....
[How to set up a Tor-Server (Hidden Service) as a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75118399/how-to-set-up-a-tor-server-hidden-service-as-a-proxy)

I have already set up the Tor service on the remote machine but now I can't set up a proxy server that I can access through Tor network.
The path of network traffic required is :
My local machine--> Tor Network--> Tor Exit Node--> Tor service at remote Server--> Web server of requested wbsite on Clearnet
And Vice versa for the response.
The Tor service itself is a proxy service accessible using the onion link.
How do I do this and how will I connect to this proxy, I mean, can I use the onion link directly in my browser's proxy setting?
The IP of the remote server is visible to the site as if the requests were originateng from there.....
I don't want to use ssh, etc
The Tor service itself is the proxy, and above path needs to be strictly followed.
The traffic is mostly going to be HTTP/HTTPS  but Socks5 would do.

---